# WPF Nested Popup does not close

Tags: wpf

I have a window with an Image that shows a Popup from its MouseEnter event handler:

```
    private void theImage_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        contolPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

There is a button in this contolPopup that shows another Popup from its Click event handler:

```
    private void setButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        paramPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

This paramPopup behaves a bit strange just after it is shown: it does not close if I click somewhere outside it, but if I click on some control inside this paramPopup and then click somewhere outside, it closes fine.

What can cause this behavior?

I tried to focus paramPopup, but this does not help:

```
    private void setButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        paramPopup.IsOpen = setButton.IsChecked??false;

        paramPopup.Focus();
    }
```

Popup.StaysOpen is set to false for both Popups. I use .NET 4.0

Below I provided full source code:

fist popup is opened from a window:

```
<Window x:Class="GeoControls.WebcamWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GeoControls"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged" Loaded="Window_Loaded" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Title="{Binding Name}"
        MouseEnter="theImage_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="theImage_MouseLeave" MouseLeftButtonUp="Window_MouseLeftButtonUp" Closed="Window_Closed">
    <Grid Background="Black">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="theImage" Width="{Binding CurrentResolution.Width}" Height="{Binding CurrentResolution.Height}" />
        <TextBlock Name="waitingTextBlock" Grid.Row="0" Text="Waiting the response from TV Server..." Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Popup Name="contolPopup" StaysOpen="False" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=theImage}" PopupAnimation="Scroll" Placement="Left" AllowsTransparency="True">
            <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Padding="10" Background="White">
                <local:WebcamControl x:Name="webcamControl" Background="White">
                </local:WebcamControl>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

the second popup is opened by ParamButtons contained in WebcamControl contained in the first popup:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GeoControls.ParamButtons"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GeoControls"
             d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

        ............ omitted some code here................                

        <Popup Name="paramPopup" StaysOpen="False" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=setButton}" AllowsTransparency="True" Closed="paramPopup_Closed">
            <Border Focusable="True" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Padding="10" Background="White">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <local:ParamSlider Grid.Column="0" x:Name="paramSlider" />
                    <Button Content="OK" Click="okButton_Click" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" />
                    <Button Content="Cancel" Click="cancelButton_Click" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: How are your `Popups` defined?  It\`s hard to tell what the issue is without knowing how they are defined and what placement they have.

Comment: added XAML source code

Comment: Strange, it works ok for me. Maybe something in Closed handler causes it to reopen, but that\`s just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

This code should help to solve the problem:

```
private void paramPopup_Closed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.Capture(null);
}
```

It is explained in more detail in this reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/33974360/16286963