# Popup inside ToolBarOverflow Panel does not work properly

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, toolbar

I have a `ToolBar` in my application which causes Problems.
I have "DropDown" Buttons inside the `ToolBar` (`ToggleButton` + `Popup`) Those DropDowns work properly if they are on the Visible Part of the `ToolBar`, they do not work properly if they are located in the `ToolBarOverflowPanel`.

If i Open a DropDown in the `ToolBarOverflowPanel` the `Popup` does not seem to receive focus. There are still hover effects (opposing to the behaviour of the same `Popup` in the visible toolbar which seems to consume all `Mouse` Events) and i can still click any other DropDown which opens the next `Popup` while the initial one stays open.

[image: Here you can see the wrong behaviour]

The following code is a full working sample to reproduce the behaviour.

```
<Window x:Class="ToolbarProblem.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="350"
    Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <ToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton"
                                  ToolTip="ToolTip"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=ContextActionPopup, Path=IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  ClickMode="Release">
                        <TextBlock Text="ICON"/>
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <Popup Name="ContextActionPopup"
                           StaysOpen="False">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" 
                                Background="White"
                                Padding="1"
                                Visibility="Visible">
                            <TextBlock Text="Content" />
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ToolBar.ItemTemplate>
    </ToolBar>
</StackPanel>
```

```
namespace ToolbarProblem
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public List<object> Items { get; } = new List<object>
        {
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object(),
            new object()
        };
    }
}
```

I did tried the following approaches without any success:

- Add some code to call `Popup.Focus`
- Change `ToggleButton.ClickMode` to everything possible
- Setting the `Popup.StaysOpen` property to true does seem to work, but is 
  of course inappropriate for my target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that your XAML will never work properly. You can find the reason in the `Popup` control code. If you set the `StaysOpen` property to false, the `Popup` when opening, will call this private method (just use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to inspect):

```
private void EstablishPopupCapture()
{
    if (!this._cacheValid[1] && this._popupRoot.Value != null && !this.StaysOpen && Mouse.Captured == null)
    {
        Mouse.Capture(this._popupRoot.Value, CaptureMode.SubTree);
        this._cacheValid[1] = true;
    }
}
```

So if there is no other control that is capturing mouse events (i.e. `Mouse.Captured == null`) your popup will capture them

> to determine when one of these events occurs outside the Popup control.

as MSDN remarks. Please, note that `Capture` method and `Captured` properties are static, so just one control at a time can capture by using `Mouse` class.

Now just take a look to the `Toolbar` default style: you will find that its `Popup` control, named "OverflowPopup", has its `StaysOpen` property set to false.

So when you click on the overflow thumb, the "OverflowPopup" calls the `EstablishPopupCapture` while it is opening. In this case `Mouse.Captured` is null so it can capture mouse events.
After a while you click on a `ToggleButton` which is inside the "OverflowPopup" (so it will continue to stay open). Now your Popup - while opening - calls `EstablishPopupCapture`, but this time `Mouse.Captured` is ***not*** null. So it is not able to listen to mouse events by using `Mouse` class.

I guess you should consider changing your XAML or adopting a different solution (for example you can write your own template for your Toolbars in order to set OverflowPopup's `StaysOpen` property to true).

This is a simplified explanation, but the fact of the matter is that it is not possible to have two or more opened popups with StaysOpen set to false: they simply cannot work as expected. Just try to run this XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Content="I am button 1" Name="btn1" Height="20" />
    <Button Content="I am button 2" Name="btn2" Height="20" />
    <Popup StaysOpen="False" IsOpen="True" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btn1}">
        <TextBlock Text="Popup1" Margin="6" Background="Red" />
    </Popup>
    <Popup StaysOpen="False" IsOpen="True" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btn2}">
        <TextBlock Text="Popup2" Margin="6" Background="Red" />
    </Popup>
</StackPanel>
```

And you will see that Popup2 will not work as it should do.

Comment: Thank you very much, i do now understand that the nested Popups with `StaysOpen` Property set to False are the Problem, i changed the toolbar to use a permanent Popup and close it manually on `Window.PreviewMouseUp`.